# Why does my stream copying procedure steadily degrades in performance

Tags: java, java-io

This code works slower and slower during copying large files. Am I doing something wrong?

```
    InputStream ms2 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/fedd/Videos/homevid.mp4"));
    OutputStream fos2 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("testfile2.mp4", true));

    try {
        int byt;
        int i = 0;
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while ((byt = ms2.read()) != -1) {
            fos2.write(byt);
            i++;
            if (i > 100000) {
                i = 0;
                long took = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
                System.out.println("100000 bytes took " + took + " milliseconds which means " + (100000000 / took) + " bytes per second");
            }
        }
        fos2.close();
        ms2.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

My Java is:

> openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
>   10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4,
>   mixed mode)

Comment: What is ms2 (ms2.read())? Check your while statement, I think there is a typo.

Comment: You are measuring time from the very beginning of the loop. You need to reset begin timestamp after printing: `time = System.currentTimeMillis();`.

Comment: BTW: it's pretty normal in most disks/SSD to have performance significantly decrease after a bit. That's due to write caches either at the kernel level or even at the hardware level. So I'd also simply test how fast you can copy the file using other tools...

Comment: Can I delete my question? :)

Comment: You should use the try with resources statement (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html ) or close the streams in the finally block else it introduces possible memory leaks due to open streams.

Comment: @EkamjitSingh, you're right, it was my InputStream. Wrong copy-paste

Comment: final code =)
https://github.com/vsetec/vsetec-utilities/blob/d23eea57da17fbbc4db2a892bbe734320548fbc3/vsetec-utilities/src/main/java/com/vsetec/utilities/ParallelStream.java#L215

Comment: @BeWu, thanks, will eventually do. This is for just a test, and I've never managed to sit until the end of the stream...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reset your base 'time' after each comparison. Try using this:

```
if (i > 100000) {
    i = 0;
    long took = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("100000 bytes took " + took + " milliseconds which means " + (100000000 / took) + " bytes per second");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your performance degrades because your calculation is wrong. For the second chunk, you are calculating the bytes per second from the second chunks size, but from both chunks time. Try adding `time = System.currentTimeMillis();` after `long took = ...`

Comment: You mean `time`, not `took`, but hell yes